# Run python plotly animation in infinite loop

Tags: python, animation, plotly

The animation from https://plot.ly/python/animations/#offline-mode as shown in the code below goes through 1 loop when created.

Is it possible to have the animation run in an infinite loop?

```
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
from IPython.display import display, HTML

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

figure = {'data': [{'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]}],
          'layout': {'xaxis': {'range': [0, 5], 'autorange': False},
                     'yaxis': {'range': [0, 5], 'autorange': False},
                     'title': 'Start Title'},
          'frames': [{'data': [{'x': [1, 2], 'y': [1, 2]}]},
                     {'data': [{'x': [1, 4], 'y': [1, 4]}]},
                     {'data': [{'x': [3, 4], 'y': [3, 4]}],
                      'layout': {'title': 'End Title'}}]}

iplot(figure)
```

Comment: How about using sleep() to make a delay in a while loop?

Comment: The plot is saved as an html file, so how would you make a loop there?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to run the animation infinitely.
First you need to know how long your animation lasts (exact value is not needed). The trick is to refresh the plot once your animation ends. The drawback of this method is that you have to redo all the steps each time you modify your plot.

- Save your animated plot as HTML.
- View source code of this HTML file.
- To refresh the plot every 5 seconds, add `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" >` to the HTML body. (Adjust the refresh rate so that the plot refreshes just after your animation ends.)
- Save changes.

## Example in Python

### Create HTML file of animated plot

```py
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    x=[1, 3, 2, 4],
    y=[1, 2, 3, 4],
    t=[2000, 2001, 2002, 2003]
))
fig = px.scatter(df, x="x", y="y",
                 animation_frame="t",
                 size='x',
                 range_x=[0, 6], range_y=[0, 6]
                 )
fig.write_html("test.html")
```

### Modify HTML file

Initially, file begins with :

```html
<html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8" /></head>
<body>
    <div>
        <script type="text/javascript">window.PlotlyConfig = {MathJaxConfig: 'local'};</script>
        <script type="text/javascript">/**

....
```

Change to :

```html
<html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8" /></head>
<body>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" >
    <div>
        <script type="text/javascript">window.PlotlyConfig = {MathJaxConfig: 'local'};</script>
        <script type="text/javascript">/**
....
```

Now each time you open the plot in the HTML file, the animation will restart every 5 seconds. (My animation lasts about 3 seconds)